# Is there a way to print tabular data, fits the terminal size using python?

Tags: python

I want to find an approach to print list as tabular table. There is many library help me to do that. But when the size of list is too long, it's not convenient to view results.

```
root@debian:~# print.py
name | score
-----+------
Tim  | 99
Ana  | 80
Jim  | 100
Tim  | 100
Tom  | 150
 ... long outputs ...
Lily | 100
Lucy | 120
```

If we can take advantage of screen width, with duplicate table on the right to reduce table length.

It's better to print as:

```
name | score      name | score      name | score
-----+------      -----+------      -----+------
Tom  | 100        Jim  | 100        Tim  | 99
Ana  | 80         Lily | 99
```

Can any lib do that?

Comment: normal editors has limit on buffer size. try using `.ipynb`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any libraries that do that but you can force to print in 3 columns just with indexing and formatted strings. Very ugly solution though:

```
import pandas as pd
import random

names = [random.choice(['Ann', 'Bill', 'Tom']) for _ in range(900)]
scores = [random.randint(0, 100) for _ in range(900)]

df = pd.DataFrame({'name': names, 'score': scores})


for idx in range(0, df.shape[0], 3):
    if idx == 0:
        print('name | score\t\t' * 3, '\n', '_____+_____\t\t' * 3, '\n')
    data = df.loc[idx: idx + 3, :]
    print(f'{data.name[idx]}\t{data.score[idx]}\t\t{data.name[idx+1]}\t{data.score[idx+1]}\t\t{data.name[idx+2]}\t{data.score[idx+2]}\n')
```

And this is the output:

```
name | score        name | score        name | score         
 _____+_____        _____+_____         _____+_____      

Ann      71          Tom    81           Tom    8

Tom      65          Tom    37           Ann    49

Bill     34          Tom    81          Bill    64
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolved by the code below:

```
import itertools
import shutil
from tabulate import tabulate


def split(a, n):
    k, m = divmod(len(a), n)
    return (a[i * k + min(i, m):(i + 1) * k + min(i + 1, m)] for i in range(n))


origin_data = [('Alice', 100) for _ in range(20)] + [('Bob', 99) for _ in range(20)]

# get the width of terminal
table_header = ['name', 'score']
table_width = len((' ' * 2).join(table_header)) + 2 * len(table_header)
table_interval = 8
col, row = shutil.get_terminal_size() or (80, 24)
dup_table_num = min((col + table_interval) // (table_width + table_interval), 10) or 1

result = ''
table_data = [[name, score] for name, score in origin_data]
tabular_lines = [str(tabulate(sd, headers=table_header, stralign='right')).split('\n') for sd in
                 (split(table_data, dup_table_num))]
for line in itertools.zip_longest(*tabular_lines, fillvalue=''):
    result += (' ' * table_interval).join(line) + '\n'

print(result)
```